# Twig/PHP вызов переменной по индексу из for

Tags: php, twig

Надо реализовать в TWIG такой код:

```
foreach ($list as $line){
    foreach ($formatlist as $form){
        if ($line[$form['var']]){
            echo $line[$form['var']];
        } else {
            echo 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Как можно вызвать переменную по ключу из Twig? 
[нерабочий вариант], проблема в том, что `line.form.var` пытается отработать как: `$line['form']['var'];`
А нужно `$line[$form['var']];`

```
{% for line in list %}
    {% for form in formatlist %}
        {% if line.form.var %}
            {{line.form.var}}
        {% else %}
            none
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Как мне верно указать индекс для вывода переменной ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение )))
Оказывается надо выводить так:

```
{% for line in list %}
    {% for form in formatlist %}
        {% if line[form.var] %}
            {{line[form.var]}}
        {% else %}
            none
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```